# Mac Pro 2013 Blank Displays And Can't Hard Reset

Tags: bootcamp, thunderbolt, hdmi, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro, Late 2013 (Trashcan) with Dual D700 Graphics and I recently installed Windows 10 using Bootcamp.

In Windows I went into the AMD FirePro Control Panel and clicked "Enable 10-bit Colour".

Windows restarted and now I just get a blank screen. I tried connecting to different displays using either the HDMI or Thunderbolt but always blank. I've rebooted several times. I've tried <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on startup but no such luch.

What have I done? Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be one of the few times that recommending reset of the SMC &  NVRAM might be in order.

NVRAM stores display config, amongst other things - see [The Eclectic Light Company - What is stored in NVRAM?](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/08/24/whats-stored-in-nvram/) (generally a knowledgeable resource)

SMC stores external video source in some Macs. I'm less certain this is going to be the useful step, but the same resource, The Eclectic Light Company mentions that treating them as a pair can be useful. SMC first, then NVRAM.
[Persistence: EFI, SMC and NVRAM](https://eclecticlight.co/2016/08/23/persistence-efi-smc-and-nvram-formerly-pram/)